# I have connected it as a client by using gorilla. After connecting it. How to close it in GO?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

As i am learning golang to work with Web socket and its connected as a client from golang but after connecting it, its not getting disconnect. So how can i close it?

```
func WebSocketClientGO() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/ws/player/BHMb1QZoiQWcOVPxa7OMd0AUL"}

    log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})


    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            }
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")

            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            c.Close()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write close:", err)
                c.Close()
                return
            }
            select {

            case <-done:
                log.Println("Done In For")
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
                log.Println("Done In For With Time")
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This is response what i get but when i want to disconnect it it wont and it stuck so suggest me about this, i have find solutions but it wasn't working

```
connecting to ws://10.68.101.13:8061/ws/player/iHel5oWq9bTQC6lJpFwSRmIga
recv: {"code":500,"data":null,"message":"Internal Error","type":"ERROR"}
interrupt
read: read tcp 10.68.101.213:55709->10.68.101.13:8061: use of closed network connection
Done In For
```

Comment: The application is written to exit on an interrupt signal and on read errors.  What happens when you type control-c (or whatever key sequence sends an interrupt signal on your system)?

Comment: I tried Ctrl+C but it is not getting close and it goes on interrupt case. Kindly refer response which i posted when i tried Ctrl+C i got that one @CeriseLimón !

Comment: The function should return given that "Done In For" is printed.  Add `defer fmt.Println("exiting WebSocketClientGO")` to the beginning of the function to confirm that function returns. Also, it looks like you attempted to gracefully close the connection with the select  at the end of the function, but that's useless given that the connection is closed before the select.  You should either delete the call to c.Close before the select. or gut the function of everything except the loops to read and write messages.

Comment: Is the program written to exit when `WebSocketClientGO` returns?

Comment: Yes @CeriseLimón

Comment: Does the `WebSocketClientGO ` function return when CTRL-C is typed?  It looks like it does based on the code and output included in the question.

Comment: No its not return anything while typed Ctrl+C @CeriseLimón

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Specifically, show the code that calls `WebSocketClientGO` and ensures that the program exits when `WebSocketClientGO` returns.